# Get page creation date Facebook?

Tags: facebook, api, date

I have had a look at the Facebook api, and I don't see anything related to a creation date, however I do need to get this from a list of about 1000 ID's, so manually getting this date wouldn't be practical.

Is there any tricks anyone can think of to get this?

Answer (score -1):

no - API does not offer this field: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#fields

Comment: I know that, I was hoping there was a 'hack' in a sense that would provide me with something similar.

Comment: as far as I know Facebook does not like "hacks". I thought you could use first post's date to get rough page creation date - but that won't work - posts could be back-dated.

Answer (score -1):

This does exist! Facebook's documentation shows you how to do this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-start-date/

This page might also help:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page-start-info/

You can also test it out in their Graph API Explorer:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

In JavaScript, using version 2.11 of the Facebook API, the code would look like this:

```
    /* make the API call */
FB.api(
    "...?fields={fieldname_of_type_PageStartDate}",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Oh okay sorry fixing it now.